# Why does Android Studio give a Null Pointer Exception warning with this code?

Tags: java, android-studio, nullpointerexception

I have the following code in Android Studio but I am getting a warning that `Method invocation 'toString()' may produce 'NullPointerException'`.

```
String source_regions_user_id = "";
if (user_ids != null && "".equals(source_region) && user_ids.containsKey(source_region) && user_ids.get(source_region) != null && user_ids.get(source_region) != "") {
    source_regions_user_id = user_ids.get(source_region).toString();
} else {
    return true; // Unable to find a matching user_id for source_region
}
```

Note that `user_ids` is a `Hashmap` and `source_region` is a `String`.

I believe I am checking for null values in everything that `toString()` relies on so why is Android Studio still giving this warning?

Comment: What is the value of `source_region` ? also the last part it seems not correct `user_ids.get(source_region) != ""` change it as the previous check `!"".equals(user_ids.get(source_region))`

Comment: @YCF_L I would change it to `! user_ids.get(source_region).isEmpty()`, or if you don't like the "distance" between `!` and `isEmpty()`, use `user_ids.get(source_region).length() != 0`

Comment: @Andreas what if `user_ids.get(source_region)` return null? but you can told me that is already checked `user_ids.get(source_region) != null` :) good point

Comment: `user_ids.containsKey(source_region)` is redundant, because if `user_ids.get(source_region) != null` is true, then `containsKey` would be true too. --- `"".equals(source_region)` ?!? Are you sure about that? You didn't miss a `!`, did you? Besides, isn't the check reduntant, given that the map wouldn't (likely) ever contain `""` as key?

Comment: I agree with you @Andreas is that comment for me :) I think the OP should clarify many parts about his code like the `user_ids` `source_region`...

Comment: @YCF_L No, that second comment is for OP.

Comment: @YCF_L Re: user_ids.get(source_region) != "" change it as the previous check !"".equals(user_ids.get(source_region)). I actually tried this and the AS IDE seems to thing that `user_ids.get(source_region)` is returning a boolean so can't compare with `.equals()`. Didn't seem right to me, but AS just wouldn't accept it.

Comment: @Andreas post a nice answer I think you can find the answer there :)

Comment: @YCF_L I agree, I need to digest that answer and work out what is gong on from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler should have been able to see that you check for null, but there *are* many conditions in the `if` statement, so perhaps it exceeded some threshold for compiler performance.

Since the `else` is nothing but a `return`, you should flip the statement around. That eliminates the need to declare the variable separately.

I've also split the conditions apart to comment on them.

```
if (user_ids == null)
    return true;
if (! "".equals(source_region)) // I think you meant the opposite check
    return true;
if (! user_ids.containsKey(source_region)) // Redundant, the next check will cover this
    return true;
if (user_ids.get(source_region) == null)
    return true;
if (user_ids.get(source_region) == "") // Object is not a string, so this will always fail
    return true;
String source_regions_user_id = user_ids.get(source_region).toString();
```

You should also use `isEmpty()` or `length()` to check for empty strings, instead of comparing to `""`.

So, taking those comments into account, we can change code to:

```
if (user_ids == null || source_region.isEmpty())
    return true;
Object obj = user_ids.get(source_region);
if (obj == null)
    return true;
String source_regions_user_id = obj.toString();
if (source_regions_user_id.isEmpty())
    return true;
// use value here
```

With this code, the compiler shouldn't get confused, so no warning, and you only lookup in the map once.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to work this info into a full solution and will update once I've given it a go.

Comment: Assigning the result of the hashmap`.get()` to an `Object`, then checking this object for `null` and using the object with `toString()` seems to do the trick.